# Service Reference not reusing data types client side

Tags: vb.net, web-services, wcf

This question has been asked many times but I can't find a solution.

I have a WCF service with a function that takes in a customer object. This customer object is in a separate project that both the client and server code reference. When I add the service reference to the client project, I choose the option to reuse data types. However, when I try to call the function on the client side and pass the customer object in, I get this error:

> Error 39  Value of type  'Real.Namespace.Customer' cannot be converted to 'Service.Namespace.Customer'.

The "Real.Namespace" is the class it should be using. "Service.Namespace" is the auto generated class created by the service reference. I know this is supposed to work, so there must be some reason why it is unable to find the real class and reuse it.

I've tried this with very simple objects and it still won't work. Any ideas on why the auto generated code can't find the real class and use it?

Edit: I've tried using a very simple object just to see if I could get it to work. So right now I'm just using a test class that looks like this:

```
Namespace DTO
<DataContract>
Public Class Test

    <DataMember>
    Public Property Name As String

End Class
End Namespace
```

Comment: Your client project must have a reference to the assembly or project containing the types you wish to reuse.

Comment: @JohnSaunders, thanks for your reply. The client project does have a reference to the project containing the Customer class. Do you know of anything that may be preventing the service from finding the class?

Comment: Is the `Customer` type a Data Contract?

Comment: I edited my question to show what my class looks like. I am just using a test class instead of customer to see if I can get that to work first. I'm not sure if I using the data contract correctly.

Comment: WCF renames the Complex types to {your service ref}.{your service namespace}{object name}. Like `MyServiceRef.MyServiceComplexType. For a service named MyService, complex type named ComplexType.

Comment: @OneFineDay, I think this is why my project is doing, if I understand you correctly. It is changing the type to MyServiceRef.Customer instead of the real object. The problem is, my client function is taking in a "real" Customer object, so the service doesn't understand it. I am trying to avoid having to copy the object to the service version property by property.

Comment: So change the client type to match the Service Ref type.

Comment: That should work. I don't know why it wouldn't, unless you don't actually have the reference you think you do. Does the referenced assembly show up in the list of assemblies when you choose "reuse reference in specific assemblies"?

Comment: @JohnSaunders, yes the reference appears in that list. I've also tried just checking off the box for that project instead of all assemblies, but that didn't make a difference. My project is able to reference the class and I don't get any compile errors, since I am using this class throughout the project. Both client/server projects target .Net 4.0.